# Downloading a file just using an URL

Tags: download, url

I created a local file as below, but when I click on the URL, browser adds the file address before actual URL (e.g. file:///G:/Proj/taxo/www.xabcd.com/~abcd/example.csv) and it does not work

```
<html>
    <head/>
        <body>
            <h1>
                <a href="www.xabcd.com/~abcd/example.csv">Download</a>
            </h1>
        </body>
</html>
```

Comment: So what is the question? If its a local file, how are you hosting it that you would expect it to be read in a way other than file:

Comment: Show us the code.

Comment: stackoverflow suggested, create a local html file with the code mentioned above and open it in any browser, then right click on the link and download by selecting "save link as" option. But I now when I added http:// in the href it is working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add an "http://" before the www.

Comment: @Shaun Mark as an answer then

Comment: I am new here please advise how to do that

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the browser.

For example, the latest Mozilla Firefox by default:

Created the file: `Book1.csv`

and typed the link in the browser address bar: `C:/Users/Paul/Desktop/Files/Book1.csv`

**It then gave the option to download the file.**

and also did as you noticed with the link:
file:`///C:/Users/Paul/Desktop/Files/Book1.csv`

If it is a .txt - the browser will display the actual text in the browser window by default.

Your question is for local files but if you are looking for a server side solution, it is possible to modify the html headers to instruct the browser. For example:http://www.vbulletin.com/forum/forum/general/chit-chat/72776-http-headers-to-force-file-to-download-rather-than-auto-open

Comment: You are right about Mozilla and it is a .txt file so it is trying to display the whole file in the browser, but it is a 10GB file hence it times out after a while. Also it is not a local file, the file is on a server as you can see the link, but after adding http:// to existing href it works, thanks for your effort.